# In The Vanishing of Ethan Carter, which elements can be considered "real"

Tags: the-vanishing-of-ethan-carter

In The Vanishing of Ethan Carter, which elements of the game's storyline can be considered to be 100% real. EG, not created by Ethan's stories.

For example, did the Vandergriff family exist at all, and did the mining accident that killed the family patriarch (As detailed in the newspaper clipping found in the bonfire near the start of the game) really happen. or was this part of one of Ethan's stories as well?

Is there an easy way to tell which elements were real?

Comment: Not backed by any evidence, hence only a comment, but I believe that it's the point of the game that you can't ever quite tell what is real and what isn't.